# What if half of your data is not normally distributed?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, nonparametric

My experiment is to test the different diets (Pk, Hg, BYD & Control) in order to check the development of insect, what are the most preferred diets by insect. For this purpose, I used 3 parameters; time (days) taken from larval to adult stage (LA), Pupal weight (PW) and Number of adults recovered (ADLT).
I have mixed count data, half normally distributed and half not normally distributed according to shapiro-wilk test, but skewness & kurtosis values are following normal distribution.
Moreover, nonparametric test (Kruskal wallis with Dunn's post hoc) giving weird results compared to ANOVA results.
So, which test should I apply on my data ?

I've also attached fig of shapiro-wilk test values.

Cheers,

Faray[image]

Comment: We can't have any idea what test to apply without knowing what your study objectives are.  Also, unless you have very large counts, a Normal distribution is an unlikely model for them, so what's the point of testing for normality?

Comment: Note that even OLS regression makes no assumption about the shape of the distribution of the independent variables - it makes assumptions about the error (which are estimated by residuals).   Also, I am not clear what your dependent variable is or how it is measured.

Comment: This is unclear. What are your data? What are you testing? Are you testing if counts are normally distributed? Are you testing your treatment assignment or some covariate? What do you mean that "Kruskal wallis... [gives] weird results compared to ANOVA"? I don't see results from either, or why 1 should be considered "weird" & the other not, so how could we advise which you should use? What do you mean that "skewness & kurtosis values are following normal distribution"? Among other things, I don't see any such values. See also @whuber's comment above, which hasn't been addressed. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You would benefit by analyzing skew, kurtosis, and QQ plots rather than the tests of normality you mention. As the comments suggest, we need to know more about your research objective to help you. Seeing what you posted, though, makes me think a multi-level model with diets nested in life stages would be interesting. Perhaps a disciminant analysis to see if life stages discriminate between diets.